# How to create one database object in another database's stored procedure?

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, synonym, object-oriented-database

scenario is, I am having 2 database. db1 and db2. where as I have around more than 45 stored procedures in db2 which are having join with tables in db1. I could able to do by `db1.dbo.tablename` but since if I am renaming db1 to db3. All db2 stored procedures getting failed. What should approach? as per client requirement as usual he want to rename db1. By find replace in script db1 to db3 is not the good approach. because if client asks to rename again db3 databse to some another name , then it is permanent tedious and unprofessional work. What should I use here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create synonyms. Reference the synonyms in your objects. If the database changes, you just have to change one synonym per object. There's no avoiding changing the logical name in your code but if you control access through synonyms you only have to change it in one place.

For example

**Without synonyms:**

Six Stored Procedures in db2 refer to objects `db1..Table1` and `db1..Table2`

When you rename `db1` to `db7`, you need to alter two objects in six stored procedures.

**With synonyms:**

Six Stored Procedures refer to synonyms `snTable1` and `snTable2` (in the local database - note no database reference here)

The synonym `snTable1` refers to `db1.Table1`

When you rename `db1` to `db7`, you need to alter two synonyms to point at the new database. No changes to stored procedures are required. All objects referring to the synonyms will still work.

This requires you to create synonyms in `db2` pointing at objects in `db1`, and an initial rewrite of your stored procedures in `db2` to refer to local synonyms instead of database-qualified objects. But you need to do that anyway right?

**Example Procedure**

1. Create a synonym in `db2` called snTable1 that refers to `Table1` in `db1`

   `USE db2`

   `CREATE SYNONYM snTable1 FOR db1.Table1`
2. Alter your 45 stored procedures to refer to `snTable1`, not `db1.Table1`. You only have to do this once. Note these stored procedures are referring to objects in the local database.
3. If your database gets renamed to xyz, recreate the synonym:

   `USE DB2`

   `DROP SYNONYM snTable1`

   `CREATE SYNONYM snTable1 FOR xyz.Table1`

This is only useful if there are far more stored procedures/views than objects.

If you wish to change these on the fly you could probably use DMO or powershell or generate some T-SQL to do it. You just run the above commands against the database with a user that has suitable security.

Another very unpleasant option that may work is to create a linked server to your local database with a hard coded login whose default database is the database that you want. But it hides the user that is really accessing the object, and probably introduces performance issues. In short it's bad practice. I question why the database needs to be renamed so much. No end user should ever see it. If you take a look at Sharepoint databases they have hideous names but this is irrelevant to an end user.

**Example linked server procedure**

1. Create a user that only has access to `db1`, and whose default database is `db1`
2. Create a linked server (called `MyLinkedServer` for example) on the SQL Server to the local database using the user created in step 1
3. Alter all your code in `db2` to use four part naming through this linked server: `SELECT * FROM MyLinkedServer...Table1`
4. If the database name changes, there are probably no changes required

This is just a theory and if it works its bad practice... worse practice than needing to rename your database.

Comment: but synonyms indicate a table name rather database name. is am I right?

Comment: Yes. You refer to a synonym in the local database. This synonym points at an object which may or may not be in another database. You define the database link in the synonym, not the in the stored procedure that refers to the synonym. See my example above.

Comment: No, But while using the synonyms in db2, I still need to use db1 name like, select * from db1.dbo.synonym1.I want to avoid db1 name itself here. or want to use some configurable name rather db1.

Comment: No. You create the synonym in the _same_ database as the stored procedure. Then you don't need to qualify it with a DB name when you refer to it. When you create the synonym, _that_ is when you hard code the database name. There is no way to avoid hard coding a database name but you can drastically reduce the number of objects that you are required to maintain. I think I got my example around the wrong way. I will clarify.

Comment: Please provide reference link or example. I couldn't get.

Comment: I have extended my answer with an example. Here's a link to the SQL Server explanation of synonyms: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187552.aspx Note it says "Provides a layer of abstraction that protects a client application from changes made to the name or location of the base object."

Comment: thats seems very cool approach.... is it possible to create alias for database only rather for each table?

Comment: You can probably effectively alias a database by using a linked server but there might be performance implications. I'll add some detail. I do question the requirement to rename the database though.

Comment: But since I am having same database server where all databases are residing. Can I link same server with it own?

Comment: Yes. You just use localhost as the server name. Try it and see. This is not really a very good solution though.

Comment: Excellent !!... One more question, Can I change server name dynamically in synonyms? you can consider switching server name based on configuration in application.

Comment: What if two people are running the app simultaneuously? There is only set of synonyms. (unless you create a default schema for each user). The more you explain you requirements, this shakier this looks. Changing a database name on the fly really raises red flags. Anyway I'll add more detail to the answer.